Is there NOT a reason to add "WITH RECOMPILE" to any script that does ALTER PROCEDURE?
Had a very odd situation where I now believe adding "with recompile" would have fixed the issue.
Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16 is there a reason to NOT include "WITH RECOMPILE" every time I script an "ALTER PROCEDURE"?
Does "With recompile" recompile all the queries in stored procedure? may be relevant.
This is a SP that gets called maybe 20 times / day, so I'm more concerned about accurate results vs. performance.
The crazy thing is SSMS results were different from the website, when calling the same stored procedure w/ the exact same parameters. This is a mis-configured SQL Server that has both a DHCP as well as hard-coded IP address in the same subnet, so I think this may be part of the root cause.
This morning I got an error

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The definition of object 'SP name' has changed since it was compiled.

when in fact nothing changed wrt the IO parameters/result set.

"This is a mis-configured SQL Server that has both a DHCP as well as hard-coded IP address in the same subnet, so I think this may be part of the root cause." very unlikely, but is an issue in itself. You should also always be connecting using FQDN not an IP address.

I don't have a good explanation for why you saw that error (I've run alter procedure while clients are executing the procedure w/o issue many many times), but as to your question "is there a reason not to add with recompile to an alter procedure statement?", yes, there is a very good reason.
By adding with recompile, you're telling SQL to recompile the procedure on every execution, not just the first one after the procedure's definition has been altered. Execution plan generation can be expensive and by recompiling on every execution you'll be incurring that cost every time (both in terms of server resources and time).
Instead, in the same page in the docs you linked to, there's a reference to sp_recompile. That will evict any existing query plan from the cache and cause the next execution of the procedure to generate a plan which will be stored.
But! alter procedure also evicts the query plan from the plan cache. I suspect that your issue was transient and that a subsequent call to the procedure would have worked just fine w/o your intervention. It's speculation on my part, but easily testable on yours.
Lastly, regarding the networking configuration of your server, two things. First, I don't think it's likely that is the issue (i.e. once a client connects via whatever mechanism, the means by which procedures are executed should be the same). Second, if you view that configuration as incorrect, change it so that it's not yet another thing on your list that could be causing the issue of the day.
